# Eclipse IDE: use file name in search within file body

Tags: eclipse

Is there a way to use the name of a file when searching for a pattern within a file?

More specifically, I want to find all files defining Java classes that contain a reference to a class name (e.g., MyClass.class) but the that class (here: MyClass) is not defined by the file (here: the name of the file is not MyClass.java)

If that is not possible with Eclipse, what else whould you suggest?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

That is not possible, as far as I know.

But a file search with the following regular expression in `*.java` files should find the described files:

```
^(?:(?:(?!/\*)(?!//)(?!\b(?:class|interface|enum)\b)[^\{])|(?:/\*(?:(?!\*/)[\s\S])*+\*/)|(?://[^\r\n]*+))*+\b(?:class|interface|enum)\s++([^\s\<]++)[\s\S]*?\b((?!\1\.)[\w_]++\.class)\b
```

Comment: That's close enough for my purpose. Thanks